# Detail ViewController's frame (in UISplitViewController) does not change its frame when autorotating?

Tags: ios, ipad, autoresize

I am having a bear of a time figuring out why in my Detail ViewController, it's frame is still 1024x768 even when in landscape mode?

I have enabled the usual suspects--I support all orientations, resizes subviews is checked...I have tried the flexible autoresize masks, everything that I can think of.

I log the coordinates of the Detail VC's frame in portrait, and it's height:1024, and a width of 768.

This never changes and it's perplexing to me.

There is not anything special being done here.  Should this resize happen automagically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this may be for the same reason as I have outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367022/catransition-not-respecting-orientation-changes-on-ipad).

But  I think you are referring to your splitViewController's view:

```
self.splitViewController.view
```

This is the outermost view and it's frame does not change.

As regards your detailedViewController's view

```
[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] view]
```

It's frame *does* change.

If you are definitely referring to your detailed view controller, then you should ignore this answer...